# Check if an option is selected on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I know there are other questions relating to this but I couldn't get the accepted answers to work for my use case.

I'm currently hiding/showing the respective div on select change, so if you select Jamaica from the dropdown menu it will only show the Jamaica div and the same for the UK and so on.

**Here's what I want to achieve:**

On page load I have the UK selected by default and I want the UK div to be shown, not the other divs. Currently they all get displayed, which isn't correct. How can I fix this? The code I have so far is: https://jsfiddle.net/33xfzvg8/1/

```
if ($("#country option:selected")){
  $('#delivery' + $('#country option:selected').val()).show();
} else {
  $('.box').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `hide` all initially and show only the selected option.

```
if ($("#country option:selected")){
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#delivery' + $('#country option:selected').val()).show();
}
```

Also, the easiest method is to `trigger` change event handler, using `trigger` method.

```
$('#country').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

```js
$('#country').change(function() {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delivery-select one-whole text-center">
  <form>
    <label for="country">Deliver to</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <!--<option value="0">Change</option>-->
      <option value="country1" name="country1" selected>United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="country2" name="country2">Jamaica</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="rte">
  <div id="deliverycountry1" class="box">
  Delivering to the UK
  </div>
  <div id="deliverycountry2" class="box">
  Delivering to Jamaica
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
if ( $('#country').val() ){
    $( '#delivery' + $("#country").val() ).show();
}

$('#country').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
});

} );
```

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/psc0uput/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could hide all the elements initially using `css`

```
.box {
  display:none;
}
```

Also note that `$("#country option:selected")` will return `object` and objects are always truthy! Check the length instead!

**Example:**

```js
if ($("#country option:selected").length) {
  $('#delivery' + $('#country option:selected').val()).show();
} else {
  $('.box').hide();
}

$('#country').change(function() {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delivery-select one-whole text-center">
  <form>
    <label for="country">Deliver to</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="country1" name="country1" selected>United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="country2" name="country2">Jamaica</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="rte">
  <div id="deliverycountry1" class="box">
    Delivering to the UK
  </div>
  <div id="deliverycountry2" class="box">
    Delivering to Jamaica
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of your query is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.box').hide();
var value = $("#country").val();
if(value)
{
 $('#delivery' +value).show();
}
else
{
 $('.box').hide();
}
})
$('#country').change(function() {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="country">Deliver to</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <!--<option value="0">Change</option>-->
      <option value="country1" name="country1" selected>United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="country2" name="country2">Jamaica</option>
    </select>

<div class="rte">
  <div id="deliverycountry1" class="box">
  Delivering to the UK
  </div>
  <div id="deliverycountry2" class="box">
  Delivering to Jamaica
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change done in JS section please view

```js
$('#country').change(function() {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#country option:selected")) {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#delivery' + $('#country option:selected').val()).show();
  } else {
    $('.box').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delivery-select one-whole text-center">
  <form>
    <label for="country">Deliver to</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <!--<option value="0">Change</option>-->
      <option value="country1" name="country1" selected>United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="country2" name="country2" >Jamaica</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="rte">
  <div id="deliverycountry1" class="box">
    Delivering to the UK
  </div>
  <div id="deliverycountry2" class="box">
    Delivering to Jamaica
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide them first, so just add `$('.box').hide();` in your first line.

```
$('.box').hide();
if ($("#country option:selected")){
$('#delivery' + $('#country option:selected').val()).show();
} else {
$('.box').hide();
}

$('#country').change(function() {
$('.box').hide();
$('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/33xfzvg8/4/